# How to call function inside function in class

Tags: python

- I have 2 class Library, Student
- If book is in displaybooks function then book is issued
- if book book is already issued then it has to print `print(bookname + "NA/already taken")`

Below is the code

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, listBooks):
         self.books = listBooks
    
    def displaybooks(self):
        for book in self.books:
            print(book)

            
    def borrowbooks(self, bookname):
        if bookname not in self.books:
            print(bookname + "NA/already taken")
        else:
            print(bookname + " is issued for you")
            
    # def deletebooksfromdisplay(self,bookname):
    #    self.books.remove(bookname)       
class Student:
    def requestbooks(self):
        self.book = input("Enter name of the book you want to borrow: ")
        return self.book
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    mylib = Library(
        ["invention", "rich&poor",  "macroeconomics", "secret"])
    student = Student()
    
    print("""CHOOSE WHAT YOU WANT TO DO:-\n1. Listing all books\n2. Borrow books \n3. 
    Exit\n""")
    while (True):
        try:
            usr_response = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

            if usr_response == 1:
                mylib.displaybooks()
            elif usr_response == 2: 
                mylib.borrowbooks(student.requestbooks())           
            elif usr_response == 3:
                print("THANK YOU ! \n")
                exit()
                break
            else:
                print("INVAILD INPUT! \n")
        except Exception as e:              #catch errors
            print(f"{e}---> INVALID INPUT! \n")
```

My output is below

```
CHOOSE WHAT YOU WANT TO DO:-
1. Listing all books
2. Borrow books 
3. 
    Exit

Enter your choice: 1
invention
rich&poor
macroeconomics
secret
Enter your choice: 2
Enter name of the book you want to borrow: secret
secret is issued
Enter your choice: 2
Enter name of the book you want to borrow: secret
secret is issued
```

You can see `secret is issued` 2 times Expected out is on second time it is `print(bookname + "NA/already taken")`

- Basically I need to write one function like below which has to delete from lisfofbooks

```
# def deletebooksfromdisplay(self,bookname):
    #    self.books.remove(bookname)
```

Comment: `Student.requestbooks` should probably take a `Library` instance as an argument, both so the library can confirm the availability of a book and so the book can be marked as checked out to the student. Right now, you are just plucking a book from thin air to give to the student to keep forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the book after borrowing it:

```
def borrowbooks(self, bookname):
    if bookname not in self.books:
        print(bookname + "NA/already taken")
    else:
        print(bookname + " is issued for you")
        self.books.remove(bookname)
```

Comment: is there any way i could write a  new function to delete books